# Bootstrap 3 - 2 columns with same column height, 2 images in same column, one image align to top, one align to bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Target Alignment:
|   img1   |  img2 |
|   img1   |               |
|   img1   |               |
|   img1   |  img3 |

css

```
.row-eq-height {  /* For same column height */
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: flex;
}
```

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-eq-height " >
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:red">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x500" class="img-responsive"/> <!-- img1-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:green">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" style="vertical-align: top"/>  <!-- img2-->
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" style="vertical-align: bottom"/>  <!-- img3-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using flexbox

```css
.parent {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  /*height: 50px;*/
  margin: 5px;
  background: DeepSkyBlue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.parent2 {
  display: flex;
}


.example-basis .parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.example-basis .item {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="example example-basis">
  <h2>flex</h2>
  <div class="example-content">
    <div class="parent2">
      <div>
        <div class="item">img1</div>
        <div class="item">img1</div>
        <div class="item">img1</div>
        <div class="item">img1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parent">
        <div class="item">img2</div>
        <div class="item">img3</div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: here is a code pen made, 
http://codepen.io/k185/pen/BWXodO?editors=1100